# Bootstrap 4 Navs Drop Down List Issue

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm developing some **Navs** forms for my university projects, I used `bootstrap@4.0.0-beta`, This is my issue, I selected  `Book item`, `navs` is working on it selected `Child` items and again click the `Organais` item after repeated Navs items details, you can check it. I attached my code in jsfiddle. please look at my code https://jsfiddle.net/9qsacmr4/4/

look at the image displayed some red color line in my issue [image: Look Image]
Thanks

Comment: This question is extremely hard to read and understand, please fix the formatting. Also instead of sharing the full code, please recreate a minimal version with your issue and post it inside the question instead of through `jsfiddle`

Comment: @BrianH. sir look at im attached the image

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: im updated my `jsfiddle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code has too many id repeated. id attribute must should be unique. I have rename some of your repeated id with number. and removed unwanted `</div>`

**inputState** -> **inputState2** and **inputState3**

Check updated jsfiddle

**EDIT**: Replaced form content with Static text.

**EDIT 2**: working with all 3 forms

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 
    
    <!-- section-two-->
    <div class="agrarian-section-addnewaccount" style="margin-top: -0.5rem;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown"> 
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Select Your Account Type </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu"> 
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="pills-dropdown1-tab" href="#pills-dropdown1" role="tab" data-toggle="pill" aria-controls="pills-dropdown1">Book</a> 
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="pills-dropdown2-tab" href="#pills-dropdown2" role="tab" data-toggle="pill" aria-controls="pills-dropdown2">Organais</a> 
                <a class="dropdown-item" id="pills-dropdown3-tab" href="#pills-dropdown3" role="tab" data-toggle="pill" aria-controls="pills-dropdown3">Child</a> 
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
          
          <!-- tab section-->
          <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-dropdown1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-dropdown1-tab">              
              <!-- tab section  head-->              
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                      <p class="WD-txt-hd">Individual Account</p>
                    </li>
                  </ol>
                </div>
              </div>              
              <!-- tab section  head-->              
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card">
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputAccNum" class="col-form-label">Account Number</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAccNum" placeholder="Account Number">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputGivName" class="col-form-label">Given Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputGivName" placeholder="Given Name">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputSurName" class="col-form-label">Sure Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSurName" placeholder="Sure Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOthName" class="col-form-label">Other Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOthName" placeholder="Other Name">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputInd-DOB" class="col-form-label">Date of Birth</label>
                          <div class="input-group input-append date" id="datePicker-IndDOB" >
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" value="" placeholder="DOB" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon add-on"> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputGENDER" class="col-form-label">Gender</label>
                          <br>
                          <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input id="radio1" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span> <span class="custom-control-description">Male</span> </label>
                          <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input id="radio2" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span> <span class="custom-control-description">Female</span> </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputNIC" class="col-form-label">NIC </label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNIC" placeholder="NIC">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputADD" class="col-form-label">Residential Address</label>
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="1" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputCity" class="col-form-label">City</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                          <label for="inputState" class="col-form-label">State</label>
                          <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Select your state</option>
                            <option value="1">One</option>
                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                            <option value="4">Four</option>
                            <option value="5">Five</option>
                            <option value="6">Six</option>
                            <option value="7">Seven</option>
                            <option value="8">Eight</option>
                            <option value="9">Nine</option>
                            <option value="10">Ten</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                          <label for="inputZip" class="col-form-label">Zip</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputMobile" class="col-form-label">Mobile</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputMobile" placeholder="Mobile">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputTeli" class="col-form-label">Teliphone</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTeli" placeholder="Teliphone">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputSrvCentre" class="col-form-label">Services Centre</label>
                          <select id="inputStatetwo" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Select your Services Centre</option>
                            <option value="1">One</option>
                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                            <option value="4">Four</option>
                            <option value="5">Five</option>
                            <option value="6">Six</option>
                            <option value="7">Seven</option>
                            <option value="8">Eight</option>
                            <option value="9">Nine</option>
                            <option value="10">Ten</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-dropdown2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-dropdown2-tab"> 
              <!-- tab section  head-->
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
                      <p class="WD-txt-hd">Organaisational Account</p>
                    </li>
                  </ol>
                </div>
              </div>
              
              <!-- tab section  head-->
              
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card">
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOrgAccNum" class="col-form-label">Account Number</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrgAccNum" placeholder="Account Number">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOrgName" class="col-form-label">Organisation Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrgName" placeholder="Organisation Name">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOrgOpenerName" class="col-form-label">Account Opener  Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrgOpenerName" placeholder="Account Opener  Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOrgOpenrMobile" class="col-form-label">Account Opener Mobile</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrgOpenrMobile" placeholder="Account Opener  Mobile">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOrgDOB" class="col-form-label">Organisation Started Date</label>
                          <div class="input-group input-append date" id="datePicker-OrgDOB" >
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" value="" placeholder="Organisation Started Date" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon add-on"> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOrgStatus" class="col-form-label">Organisation Status</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrgStatus" placeholder="Organisation Status">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOrgRegNumber" class="col-form-label">Organisation Reg: Number </label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrgRegNumber" placeholder="Organisation Reg: Number">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOrgADD" class="col-form-label">Organisation Address</label>
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="OrgADD" rows="1" placeholder="Organisation Address"></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputCity" class="col-form-label">City</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                          <label for="inputState2" class="col-form-label">State</label>
                          <select id="inputState2" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Select your state</option>
                            <option value="1">One</option>
                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                            <option value="4">Four</option>
                            <option value="5">Five</option>
                            <option value="6">Six</option>
                            <option value="7">Seven</option>
                            <option value="8">Eight</option>
                            <option value="9">Nine</option>
                            <option value="10">Ten</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                          <label for="inputZip" class="col-form-label"> Zip </label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOegEmail" class="col-form-label"> Organisation Email </label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputOrgEmail" placeholder="Organisation Email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOrgTeli" class="col-form-label"> Teliphone </label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrgTeli" placeholder="Organisation Teliphone">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputSrvCentre" class="col-form-label"> Services Centre </label>
                          <select id="inputStatetwo2" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Select your Services Centre</option>
                            <option value="1">One</option>
                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                            <option value="4">Four</option>
                            <option value="5">Five</option>
                            <option value="6">Six</option>
                            <option value="7">Seven</option>
                            <option value="8">Eight</option>
                            <option value="9">Nine</option>
                            <option value="10">Ten</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div  class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-dropdown3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-dropdown3-tab"> 
              
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
                      <p class="WD-txt-hd">Children Account</p>
                    </li>
                  </ol>
                </div>
              </div>
              
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="card">
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputOrgAccNum" class="col-form-label">Account Number</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrgAccNum2" placeholder="Account Number">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputChildGivName" class="col-form-label">Given Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputChildGivName" placeholder="Given Name">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputChildOpenerName" class="col-form-label">Sure Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputChildOpenerName" placeholder="Sure Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputChildOpenrOther" class="col-form-label">Other Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputChildOpenrOther" placeholder="Other Name">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputChildDOB" class="col-form-label">Date Of Birth</label>
                          <div class="input-group input-append date" id="datePicker-ChildDOB" >
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" value="" placeholder="DOB" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon add-on"> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputChildGENDER" class="col-form-label">Gender</label>
                          <br>
                          <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input id="Childradio1" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span> <span class="custom-control-description">Male</span> </label>
                          <label class="custom-control custom-radio">
                            <input id="Childradio2" name="radio" type="radio" class="custom-control-input">
                            <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span> <span class="custom-control-description">Female</span> </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputChildADD" class="col-form-label">Residential Address</label>
                          <textarea class="form-control" id="ChildADD" rows="1" placeholder="Residential Address"></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputCity" class="col-form-label">City</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity3">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                          <label for="inputState3" class="col-form-label">State</label>
                          <select id="inputState3" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Select your state</option>
                            <option value="1">One</option>
                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                            <option value="4">Four</option>
                            <option value="5">Five</option>
                            <option value="6">Six</option>
                            <option value="7">Seven</option>
                            <option value="8">Eight</option>
                            <option value="9">Nine</option>
                            <option value="10">Ten</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                          <label for="inputZip" class="col-form-label">Zip</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip2">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputChildMobie" class="col-form-label">Mobile</label>
                          <input type="Text" class="form-control" id="inputChildMobile" placeholder="Mobile">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputChildTeli" class="col-form-label">Teliphone</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputChildTeli" placeholder="Teliphone">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputChildGuardianName" class="col-form-label">Guardian Name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputChildGuardianName" placeholder="Guardian Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                          <label for="inputSrvCentre2" class="col-form-label">Services Centre</label>
                          <select id="inputStatetwoe2" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Select your Services Centre</option>
                            <option value="1">One</option>
                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                            <option value="4">Four</option>
                            <option value="5">Five</option>
                            <option value="6">Six</option>
                            <option value="7">Seven</option>
                            <option value="8">Eight</option>
                            <option value="9">Nine</option>
                            <option value="10">Ten</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <!-- /tab section--> 
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir are you sure its working right now? please can you check it, first click 3rd drop down item after click 2nd item you can see its repeated

Comment: @core114 It appears that issue was with your 3rd form which was in Child tab. I have removed inner forms from content with text. just replace with your form code.

Comment: Sir, im replaced it , without form its working, im added again form ,now its not work

Comment: @core114 check again my updated fiddle. It's working.

Comment: sir what do you changed it? can you please explain little bit

Comment: your code has so many unwanted close tags, id confliction and there was missing `</select>`.  Kindly accept answer if it solved your issue. thanks. @core114

Comment: sir, i got it and  its working right now ,  thanks for you valuable time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155339/discussion-between-core114-and-jignesh-bhavani).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add `J-query` script and add `java script` then add `select box for drop down`. `select box drop down`  value set `main form div class`. example : `<select> <option value="book">Book</option> </select>` `<div class="book box">` Put Form Here

Check this Below Link

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/DEVPIYUSH/98rb0xsf/

Comment: sir, please give me a some little description, what do you changed

Comment: Add Jquery script and add javascript then add select box for dropdown. select box dropdown value set main form div class. example : <select> <option value="book">Book</option> </select><div class="book box">Put Form Here</div>